# Stack Overflow API ignores Accept-Encoding header

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api

I'd like to get plain simple JSON and tried to tell the server [not to send gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321455/what-encoding-string-tells-a-web-server-not-to-send-gzip-content), like this:

```
wget -d "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow"
wget -d --header="Accept-Encoding:identity" "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow"
wget -d --header="Accept-Encoding:gzip;q=0,deflate,sdch" "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow"
```

But I constantly get a zipped response. Doesn't this violate [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3)?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression

Comment: Thanks, missed this part of the documentation